# Yii2 findOne() exceeding execution time

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a action that is doing a simple findOne($id) query and returning the one row from the database. This is exceeding maximum execution time. This method is being inherited by multiple classes where is works perfectly fine. I am not overriding any `find()` or `afterFind()` methods in the relevant Model.

```
   public function actionGetone($id)
    {
        $classname = $this->model;
        $model = new $classname;
        return $model::findOne($id);
    }
```

I don't get any errors and works as expected if I override the method with:

```
public function actionGetone($id){
        $items = Job::find()->where(['id' => $id])->all();
        return $items;
    }
```

but as soon as I change it to return `return $items[0];` id dies again with same Exceeded error.

Not sure if this is linked but I'm getting a `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` error when the action is not mentioned in the `behaviours()` method and when it is added to access rule like below. But it gives me a `Call to a member function checkAccess() on null` error when i change access role to ['*']. I don't have authManager setup.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'contentNegotiator' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ],
        'authenticator' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            'only' => [ 'delete','patch','getone'],
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['delete','patch','getone'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['delete','patch','getone'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ];
}
```

I'd appreciate any ideas :)

**Update**

```
$items = Job::find()->where(['id' => $id]);
return $items;
```

Gives:

```
{
  "sql": null,
  "on": null,
  "joinWith": null,
  "select": null,
  "selectOption": null,
  "distinct": null,
  "from": null,
  "groupBy": null,
  "join": null,
  "having": null,
  "union": null,
  "params": [],
  "where": {
    "id": "3"
  },
  "limit": null,
  "offset": null,
  "orderBy": null,
  "indexBy": null,
  "modelClass": "common\models\Job",
  "with": null,
  "asArray": null,
  "multiple": null,
  "primaryModel": null,
  "link": null,
  "via": null,
  "inverseOf": null
}
```

Comment: Is `id` the primary key? If not, is it indexed? How many rows do you have? If you print out the SQL and paste it directly in your DB does it run fine? Have you tried printing out the query with `print_r` before using `->all()`?

Comment: you can print the activeQuery with this command: $query->createCommand()->rawSql;

Comment: I only have 28 rows in my db. `var_dump($model->primaryKey()) ;` gives me  `[0=>'id']`

Comment: try removing all behaviors and check if it works, if it does there is something wrong in one of your behaviors, find out which one

Comment: the queryall is working fine and only returning one result as expected. Why would grabbing the first item of array result in exceeded execution time?

Comment: removing all behaviours gives me same execution time exceeded error

Comment: did you try to print the query and paste it directly in your DB like @h2ooooooo suggested?

Comment: @JPickup From your recent edit it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the query - my bet is that it's some sort of infinite loop for whatever reason. Do you have an IDE that can do breakpoints? Could you go through the code and see what's going on? What happens if you create a new model from scratch without any fancy stuff but the same table name and try with that? Could you try, just for fun, to `return [$items[0]]` (perhaps it calls the method again if it receives a non-array, and that's why it works with an array?

Comment: @h2ooooooo you're right, got it at the same time :) thank you

Comment: @JPickup You're very welcome - glad you figured it out! Could you update your answer with info on how you fixed it, and not just where the error was? :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, its to do with the recursive flag in the model's `toArray()` method. In my case, a `user` has `jobs` and a `job` has `users` specified in the model's `fields()` methods. Which is resulting in an infinite loop.

Add this to the relation's model to avoid the infinite loop:

```
public function toArray(array $fields = [], array $expand = [], $recursive = true)
{
    return parent::toArray($fields, $expand, false);
}
```